# javascript - How to get nested object from a FormData object [object Object]

Tags: javascript, json, object, form-data

I want to get the entire nested object (with all the props) of a value that is stored in a FormData.
This is possible?

### Example

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('k1', 123);
formData.append('k2', 'ABC');
formData.append('k3', {
  a: 1,
  b: '2'
});

data = {};
formData.forEach((value, key) => {
  console.log(`Key: ${key}`, {
    key,
    value,
    type: typeof(value),
    getResult: formData.get(key),
    getAllResult: JSON.stringify(formData.getAll(key))
  });

  data[key] = value;
});

console.warn('Final result', {
  data
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

There is a way to capture the keys and values of the `k3` without using jQuery or any external library?

Comment: The FormData API has pretty much everything you'd need https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData specifically if you set multiple values for a single key, the getAll() API should return this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/getAll

Comment: Why are you trying to store an object in a formData instance?

Comment: Yeah I just realized that the value you are setting "looks" like an object, but this isn't supported https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append will convert that to a single string.  If this is what you do want, then you'll need to parse the JSON when you retrieve the value back out

Comment: @scunliffe the method getAll is returning a string with 'object Object'

Comment: @MiBol correct, because of the comment just above... the FormData API is just a convenience layer on top of the current HTTP Web forms... so you can either have a single key (e.g. field name) with a single string value, or you can repeat the key multiple times to store a "list/array" of single values. If you *need* to pass an object, you'll need to stringify your object to pass as a string, then parse it out after.

Comment: @ChrisG it's the way how it's implemented right now in the system, which does not make a lot of sense to me

Comment: To send objects in formData, they're usually converted to JSON. However, again, why store an object like this? If this is ultimately about sending the formData to the server, stringifying it is necessary anyway. And if this is about being able to get the object back out of formData, then storing it in there in the first place is utter nonsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so this isn't quite what you're after, but here goes. If you want to pass in an object for your `k3` value, then you'll need to `stringify` it first.   You'll then need to parse it back out to an object wherever you want to use it. I've updated your code above to stringify the value, and *attempt* to parse it back out in your debugging (just so that you can see it)

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('k1', 123);
formData.append('k2', 'ABC');
formData.append('k3', JSON.stringify({
  a: 1,
  b: '2'
}));

data = {};
formData.forEach((value, key) => {
  console.log(`Key: ${key}`, {
    key,
    value,
    type: typeof(value),
    rawResult: formData.get(key),
    potentialObjResult: (function(val){
         let potential = undefined;
         try {
            potential = JSON.parse(val);
         } catch(ex){
             console.log('could not parse: <' + val + '> as JSON');
         }
         return potential;
     })(formData.get(key))
    });
  data[key] = value;
});

console.warn('Final result', {
  data
});
```

Comment: It's a fair way to get things done. Then, in a short, the way of it's implemented there is not a way to get the entire object. Pretty clear answer!

Comment: It might not be a typical use case, but the ability/desire to pass arbitrary data to the server is pretty common.  `endpoint.html?data={a:1,b:'2',c:true}` or things like: `endpoint.html?selectedOptions=[3,7,15,38,241]` especially if your server side can parse JSON easily/natively.

Comment: Passing it to the server, absolutely. But getting it back out of formData? Why?

Comment: Yeah I presumed here that that was only for the OP’s debugging purposes… I’m not recommending to keep that.